# Testing OpenSSH logging

Tags: sshd, docker, rsyslog, alpine-linux

I'm attempting to turn on logging inside OpenSSH running in an Alpine Docker container.

I made sure to install `rsyslog` and start the daemon with `/usr/sbin/rsyslogd`.

My sshd logging settings are as follows:

```
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

After making the configuration change I kill the sshd process and restart it with `/usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

I then ssh into the localhost and exit.  I'm assuming that I should be seeing a `/var/log/auth.log`, but no such file appears.

Comment: did you configure the `rsyslog` to catch these messages? Do you have `journald` in container?

Comment: I'm brand new to rsyslog and the corresponding logging configuration options for OpenSSH.  Based on my research it looks like I just need to add: `auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log`.  Currently this line is in the default configuration `authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure `, but that does not trigger any logging.  I don't think alpine has a journald package.  At least running `apk add journald` does not work ...

Comment: OK - Looks like journald might be baked in because after changing the configuration I now get the `/var/log/auth.log` generated.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, what config did you change to get it working?

Comment: It's been a while but I think I just changed `authpriv.* /var/log/secure` to `auth,authpriv.* /var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: For those who may come across this question, as I did, while trying to run `sshd` as the main/only service in the Docker container, you may instead want to [send sshd logs to standard out](https://serverfault.com/a/966104/200375) by starting as `sshd -D -e`.