# Missing syslog entries for OpenSSH

Tags: ssh, logs, opensuse, syslog, rsyslog

I would like to save the log for OpenSSH client. The [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html) says that I can use

```bsh
ssh -y example.com
```

to turn on logging. [Configuration manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) says that the default Syslog facility is user; I didn't touch it in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/config`. In addition, my syslog config has

```
user.* /var/log/user.log;RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
```

so I expect to find my SSH logs in `/var/log/user.log`. However, I tried `ssh -y`, and there’s no “ssh” in that file. I also tried

```bsh
journalctl -t ssh
```

It seems to be for sshd, not for the client. Is this expected? Any one made client-side SSH syslog working?

Or is there any more configuration I need to check/add?

I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275447/testing-openssh-logging) but it’s about server-side logging, and it is about changing the Syslog facility. I don’t care about Syslog facility, as long as there is some log there.

Answer (score 0):

In [Configuration manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) it's also stated that default `loglevel` is `INFO`

> LogLevel
> Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages
> from ssh(1).  The possible values are: QUIET, FATAL, ERROR,
> INFO, VERBOSE, DEBUG, DEBUG1, DEBUG2, and DEBUG3.  The default
> is INFO.  DEBUG and DEBUG1 are equivalent.  DEBUG2 and DEBUG3
> each specify higher levels of verbose output.

So it could be worth trying to increase the `loglevel` according to your needs.
Below examples with debug level.

Via command line according to [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html):
`ssh -v -y example.com`

> -v
> Verbose mode.
> Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its
> progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentica‐
> tion, and configuration problems.  Multiple -v options increase
> the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.

Via ssh_config according to [Configuration manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html):
`LogLevel DEBUG`

> LogLevel
> Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages
> from ssh(1).  The possible values are: QUIET, FATAL, ERROR,
> INFO, VERBOSE, DEBUG, DEBUG1, DEBUG2, and DEBUG3.  The default
> is INFO.  DEBUG and DEBUG1 are equivalent.  DEBUG2 and DEBUG3
> each specify higher levels of verbose output.